# How to get government to build a road to isolated villages because of the snow and altitude?

Tags: society, economy, climate, politics, government

Village background:

These regions are relatively humid with irregular precipitations but occasionally torrential. Generally it falls annually between 600 mm to 1000 mm. The drought in the summer months, interrupted by thunderstorms, is usually intense. Snow falls between November and April, but can persist from September to June in the peaks. Important rivers flow through the valleys .

The issue here is how to get the government who partially neglected these areas to build a road up there and get them some education in addition to continuous monitoring of the roads in case of snow to prevent locking them up.

On an other issue, how to build an economy for these guys who can't seem to earn a living?

One more note, what kind of economic activity would be suitable for regions of such characteristics? (Tourism ideas, for example. . .)

Comment: Invent skis and snowboards?

Comment: I saw a documentary about a Chinese village that gave up waiting for the government to build a road. They built one themselves, blasting a ledge (in places a tunnel) along the side of the mountain they lived on top of.

Comment: What's the level of technology here?

Comment: The level is below zero !! We're talking about donkeys for moving around and steep mountains hard to cross.

Answer (score 6):

How to get a government to do anything?  It needs to believe it is in its best interest to do so.   Often the question is asked, "What is the return on my investment?"  Positive financial answers make it very easy.  If by creating a road to some remote location will not only pay for itself but bring in revenue above and beyond its maintenance, then it will be very interested in doing so.  Tourism might be one reason to do so, but usually that will be a benefit of having better passable roads, than a reason to do so in the first place.

If the road makes it much easier to reach some valuable resource, or makes the transportation cheap enough then that is the most likely reason for the road to be built.

Now other reasons that might help it along?  if putting a road through the area makes a better connection between two places that could use better transportation.  Maybe a city to some good farm land so help feed the city and reduce costs of transportation.

The last is public pressure.  If enough of the public think that the road should be built (for whatever reason) then regardless of other costs, the road will be built.  This is for a government that has some concern over the welfare and opinions of its populace.

Comment: Yeah, money is always good motive. Beside what bowlturner listed they could also collect toll for using a road and making it source of income. win-win

Answer (score 0):

Russia might be an interesting real-world example to look at. Many cities in Russia are incredibly remote, yet have transportation to them and infrastructure within. This is usually to accommodate industry (that is perhaps near water, or purposefully isolated) or access to remote natural resources.

Modern day Canada would also be an example in regards to natural resources. The Alberta Tar Sands and the Northern Territory Diamond mines being good examples.

Perhaps other economic and non-economic motivations could include:

- tourism
- national pride
- sense of democracy/equality
- militaristic (access to remote, but potentially geographically strategic areas)
- trade routes

Answer (score 0):

## Try ice mining!

> The drought in the summer months, interrupted by thunderstorms, is usually intense.

Any region will become economically prosperous if it produces or handles some commodity that is extremely valuable. In this case, the really valuable commodity (during the summer months, so from about June-August) is water. Where can you find large quantities of water for most of the year? Locked up in ice, high in the peaks.

It looks like during September-November and April-June, these remote areas will have the main supplies of snow and ice in the country. During the last few months of spring, it will be necessary to prepare for the coming drought by stocking up on water, in the form of ice. It seems safe to assume that the peaks will have received higher quantities of snow/ice during the winter, and so they will have large stores still remaining come April. The government can take advantage of this by shipping out excess snow/ice during spring, letting it melt, and then slowly using it over the summer drought.

That will make for an incredible healthy economy for those spring months, and the desperate need for water will most likely make the government more inclined to make permanent roads/railway lines there, so there will be guaranteed paths to the peaks when necessary.

Welcome to the land of ice mining!

Back in the 19th century, by the way, [the ice trade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_trade) was extremely important in parts of the United States, becoming an important industry to help enable cooling of meats, produce, and other perishable items. Here's a picture of what ice harvesting (in Indiana) looked like:

[image]

<sup>Image in the public domain (in the United States).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I second Russia as an example. The situation you describe is very much similar to the North-Eastern Siberia (aka Kolyma). The region is incredibly rich in all sorts of ores and minerals, and is actively mined since 1930ies (see Gulag).

However, there is not a single road connecting Magadan to mainland, except a winter snow path to equally remote Yakutsk (there is even no bridge across Lena river). The roads from Magadan into the proper Kolyma are also seasonal.

And yes there are permanent settlements there. But no permanent roads. Go figure.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to make organizations to -want- to do things, many of which have been mentioned. Perhaps there's a certain luxury good that's only produced by these artisans, or a cache of materials, or some sort of resource that's abundant in that area. All of these potentially give the government a positive gain from their financial expenditures.

Another reason for investment is cultural. Perhaps a major religious/political/cultural figure claims this village as their hometown. Maybe there's a major temple, school, etc in the region. While a politician might not get monetary rewards for investing in the area, they add to their personal humanitarian prestige. If the government in question answers in any way to its citizens- even just to avoid unrest- this could be important. For instance, many temples in areas such as China and Nepal are very remote, but regarded worldwide as centers for learning and spirituality, to the extent that people will initiate pilgrimages to those sites.